# Draw 3 triangles with css

Tags: css

[image: I am trying to make this design]

I am trying to make the design above in CSS.
I tried using clip-path to make the triangle in the centre but then the blue and green triangles can't be seen. How can I make this the width of the screen and responsive too?

These are the clip paths for the triangle:

```css
.centerTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  background-color: red;
}

.leftTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.rightTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftTriangle"></div>
<div class="centerTriangle"></div>
<div class="rightTriangle"></div>
```

Would appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gradients can do it:

```css
html {
  min-height:100%;
  
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,blue  50%,red 0) left /50.1% 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top left ,green 50%,red 0) right/50.1% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: you are a genius @temani (this is not my question, but learned something new)

Comment: And here I was, fumbling around with `conic-gradient`... nicely done! (Obviously I'd *prefer* the answer be explained in detail, but even so: very nice)

Comment: @DavidThomas conic-gradient can do this once we will have Trigo function available and the ability to divide two units to get a uniteless value. The code will look like this: `conic-gradient(from -180deg at bottom,blue atan(1vh/1vw),red 0 calc(180deg - atan(1vh/1vw)),green 0)` .. maybe it will work in one or two years :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a responsive version using border:

```css
body {
  border-top: 100vh solid red;
  border-left: 50vw solid blue;
  border-right: 50vw solid green;
  margin:0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to make it work with three divs, here is my solution

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.container *{
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0
}

.centerTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 50% 100%, 100% 0);
  background-color: red;
  
}

.leftTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 50% 100%);
  background-color: blue;
}

.rightTriangle {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 50% 100%);
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftTriangle"></div>
  <div class="centerTriangle"></div>
  <div class="rightTriangle"></div>
</div>
```